# js fill array than replace with value

Tags: javascript

My goal is start with an array
with null values than if an other
array has entries replace accordingly
just to do en example

```
const a = [...[null,null,null, null], ...[1,2,3,4]]
```

I want an array **[1,2,3,4]**

at start the second array could be also empty like

```
const a = [...[null,null,null, null], ...[]]
```

or

```
const a = [...[null,null,null, null], ...[1]]
```

and so on ....

```
const a = [null,null,null, null];
const b = [1,2,3];
const c = a.map((item,i)=> b[i] ? b[i] : a[i])
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: What is your expected result for the second and third examples you've given? Or when you have `[...[null,null,null, null], ...[1,2]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with an array as target and get the values updated which are at the same index/key.

This works with sparse arrays as well.

```js
const a = [null, null, null, null];
const b = [1, 2, 3, , 5];

// creating new, rather than mutating
const c = Object.assign([], a, b); 

console.log(c); // [1, 2, 3, null, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it out. just a simple for loop. I use Number.isNaN to do the validation. You can use other validations if you need to validate other kind of values.

```
    const a = [null,null,null, null];
    const b = [1,2,3];

    let c=[...a]
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if(!Number.isNaN(b[i])){
            c[i]=b[i]
        }
    }
```

This is the output:

[ 1, 2, 3, null ]